# Show static user-set message in the notification bar on the Ubuntu panel (xfce)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification, panel, customization

I'm running on Xubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way to add a specific text box to the notification taskbar on the top of the screen? i.e.

[image: indicator-ip]

but I don't need the dropdown menu or any of that fancy stuff. All I want is a single text box that I can define a string for and will come up at boot forever and ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [xfce4-genmon-plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin), which displays any string or image with dropdowns if necessary.

[image]

First install it with

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-genmon-plugin
```

Add the applet to the panel, and from the panel configuration dialog, enter the command in the Command field of the Properties section of the plugin. The output of this command will be displayed on the panel